# How to setup Extract filter

Tags: tableau-api

How to the setup or configure my extract filters in tableau to always load the current data when admin refreshes the extract

Below is an example of data in the base
Date Amount
Jan-20 40.00
Jan-20 78.00
Feb-20 70.00
Feb-20 56.00

In March , March 2020 data will be added to the database. & When the tableau extract refreshes automatically I want only March 2020 data feeding my dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

You should set incremental refresh when you extract the data. With incremental refresh you should identify a field that is going to be checked on when refreshing.
In your example, you can use Month-Year. When you refresh you click on the incremental refresh on desktop and when you refresh on server, it will do incremental refresh since you already set it up.

[image]

[image]